# Chrome hides last menu item. Explorer and Firefox works well

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, menu, uinavigationbar, menuitem

I have nine items in my main menu (navigation bar). When I click the first, the second or the third item, then the last item of the main menu becomes hidden, otherwise the last item is visible. Label of the last item is "Kontakt". This issue occurs in Chrome. All menu items are visible in Firefox and Explorer all the time. Please, could anyone help? web: www.cosiv.cz

Answer (score 0):

**You should always provide the html & css needed to help you**, instead of linking to a site.

Still, try this in your css:

Change

```
nav.inline > ul > li,
nav.inline > ol > li,
nav.inline > div > ul > li,
nav.inline > div > ol > li {
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

To this:

```
nav.inline > ul > li,
nav.inline > ol > li,
nav.inline > div > ul > li,
nav.inline > div > ol > li {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

This is provided as a quick fix. What's happening is that in Chrome some padding or margin is getting some extra pixels and pushing that last menu item beneath the menu, hiding it under the website content.